# How do I pass parameters to the ldapjs exop() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap, asn.1, ber

I'm trying to use the "Change User's Password" extended operation, as defined in [this RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3062) which states that it takes a sequence of three optional parameters. However, it seems that ldapjs's client.exop() function only allows me to provide it with a string or buffer.

This is my attempt:

```js
const dn = `uid=${username},ou=People,dc=${orginization},dc=com`
client.exop('1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.1', [dn, null, newPassword], (err, value, res) => {
  // ...
})
```

And this is the resulting error:

```
TypeError: options.requestValue must be a buffer or a string
```

How am I supposed to encode those values into a string? The ldapjs documentation gives very little information about passing parameters to an extended operation.

Answer (score 2):

**TL:DR;** The extended operation parameters need to be ASN.1 values encoded with the BER standard. This isn't a trivial task, so you might want an additional npm library, such as [asn1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asn1) to help with this process.

After combing through ldapjs's code, reading up a bunch about ASN.1 and how LDAP uses the ASN.1 standard, and some trial and error, I was finally able to resolve this issue. Because of the distinct lack of documentation for this, I thought I would share what I learned on stackoverflow so others don't need to go through as much trouble as I did.

### A working example

This uses the [asn1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asn1) npm library to encode the data being sent.

```
const { Ber } = require('asn1')

// ...

const CTX_SPECIFIC_CLASS = 0b10 << 6
const writer = new Ber.Writer()
writer.startSequence()
writer.writeString(dn, CTX_SPECIFIC_CLASS | 0) // sequence item number 0
// I'm choosing to omit the optional sequence item number 1
writer.writeString(newPassword, CTX_SPECIFIC_CLASS | 2) // sequence item number 2
writer.endSequence()
client.exop('1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.1', writer.buffer, (err, value, res) => {
  // ...
})
```

### What is ASN.1?

ASN.1 is a language that's used to describe an interface for an object. These interfaces are special in that they are language agnostic - i.e. javascript can create an object that conforms to one of these interfaces, encode it, and send it to a python server which then decodes and validates the object against the same interface. Much of ASN.1 is not relevant to what we're trying to accomplish, but it's important to note that what we're trying to do is make an object that conforms to one of these ASN.1 interfaces (LDAP is built all around them).

### What is BER?

BER describes a standard way to represent an object that conforms to an ASN.1 interface. Using the BER standard, we can encode javascript data into a buffer that can be understood by an LDAP server.

### BER basics

BER is designed to be a very compact encoding standard. I'll go over the basics here, but I highly recommend [this article](https://ldap.com/ldapv3-wire-protocol-reference-asn1-ber/) if you want to get into more details about the binary representation of BER (it's tailored to LDAP users). [A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) is another great resource.

ASN.1 describes a number of basic object types, such as strings and numbers, and It describes structured object types such as a sequence or set. It also provides the power for users to use their own custom types.

In BER, each piece of data is prefixed by two bytes (usually): An identifier byte and a length-of-data byte. The identifier byte tags the data with information about the kind of data it contains (A string? sequence? custom type?). There are four "classes" of tags: universal (such as a string), application (LDAP defined some application tags which you might encounter), context-specific (See the "BER Sequences" section below), and private (not likely applicable here). A string tag's bit sequence will always be interpreted as a string tag, but the meaning for the bit sequence of a custom tag may vary on the environment, or even within a request.

In the asn1 npm library, you can write out a string element as follows:

```
writer.writeString('text')
```

To find all of the available functions, the author of this library asks that you peek into [the source code](https://github.com/joyent/node-asn1/blob/v0.2.3/lib/ber/writer.js).

### BER Sequences

A sequence is used to describe an object (a set of key-value pairs) with a particular shape. Some elements may be optional while others are required. The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3062) I was following gave the following description for its parameters. We need to conform to this sequence's interface in order to send our password reset parameters to LDAP.

```
PasswdModifyRequestValue ::= SEQUENCE {
  userIdentity    [0]  OCTET STRING OPTIONAL
  oldPasswd       [1]  OCTET STRING OPTIONAL
  newPasswd       [2]  OCTET STRING OPTIONAL }
```

The `[0]`, `[1]`, and `[2]` all refer to context-specific tag numbers. A value tagged with the context-specific tag of 1 will be interpreted as the value for the oldPasswd argument. We don't need to use the global string tag to indicate that our value is of type string - LDAP can already infer that information using the interface we're conforming to. This means when writing a string in this sequence, instead of doing `writer.writeString('text')` as done before (which automatically used the global string tag), a tag number must be provided as follows:

```
const CTX_SPECIFIC_CLASS = 0b10 << 6
writer.writeString(newPassword, CTX_SPECIFIC_CLASS | 2) // The second optional parameter allows you to set a custom tag on the data being set (instead of the default string tag).
```

The first two bits of the tag byte are reserved for specifying the tag class (in this case, it's the context-specific class, or bits "10"). So, `CTX_SPECIFIC_CLASS | 2` refers to the newPasswd sequence item described by the RFC. Note that if I want to omit an optional sequence entry, I just don't write out a value tagged with that sequence id.

### Concluding Remarks

Hopefully this should give readers enough information to be able to format and send BER-encoded parameters for an extended LDAP operation. I do want to note that I am no ASN.1/BER expert - all of this information above is just how I understood these concepts from my own research over the past couple of days. So, there are likely a few things mis-explained in this post. Feel free to edit it if you happen to be more knowledgeable than me about this topic.